# simulation with arena

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate a supermarket with the arena to find the proper number of cashiers which market needs.
I want to start the simulation with one cashier then increase the number of cashiers in next simulations until the utilization of cashiers is less than 70%.

each cashier is a "resource module" and has a "process module" for it's service time.

am I make a separate model for each different number of the cashier(for example a model for a supermarket with one cashier, another model for a supermarket with two cashiers and so on) or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little more advance but it sounds like Arena's Process Analyzer would help you determine the number of cashiers needed.

> - **The Process Analyzer** assists in the evaluation of alternatives
>     presented by the execution of different simulation model scenarios.
>     This is useful to simulation model developers, as well as decision-
>     makers
> - **The Process Analyzer** is focused at post-model development
>     comparison of models. The role of the Process Analyzer then is to
>     allow for comparison of the outputs from validated models based on
>     different model inputs.

via [pelincec.isep.pw.edu.pl/doc/Simulation_Warsaw%20Part%205.pdf](http://pelincec.isep.pw.edu.pl/doc/Simulation_Warsaw%20Part%205.pdf)

A Google search for Arena Process Analyzer provides plenty of lecture notes, book references and examples:
https://www.google.com/search?q=arena+process+analyzer

Also, it sounds like this model isn't very complicated so, although it may be tedious, it'll probably be quicker to alter your model and run *n* simulations for each solution {1 cashier, 2 cashiers, ...}.

Also, if the model is indeed pretty simple, why not create multiple independent models in the same simulation file. For instance, one simulation file has three independent models of 1, 2 and 3 cashiers. The next has 4, 5 and 6 cashiers and so on. This would consolidate the statistics a little more and make analysis easier.

Comment: If he believes that utilization will be monotonically decreasing with increased # of servers, then manually altering the model to run {1 cashier, 2, ...} is almost certainly the easiest way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this without making multiple models. A cashier is simply a resource, but it could also be an entity.

You can build your model to require throughput (customers) to be processed when two entities are available - a register entity and a cashier entity. This could be done with a batch module.

cashier entities would be set up according to a schedule you would like to test... from minimum cashier availability to full cashier availability.

Register entities would probably be held constant, but you could make them variable according to a schedule, too.

Your batched entity would then go into the process entity until a schedule called for the cashier to "leave" the system - split the batch and destroy the cashier entity. Register entity loops back to the batch to be grouped with another cashier or wait.